# Boost property-tree access violation

Tags: c++, xml, boost, access-violation, boost-propertytree

I have been trying to parse an XML file using boost's property tree, but every time I want to get the value of a string it throws an access violation exception. It works fine with integers so I'm a bit confused.
Here's some of the code:

```
class Config
{
    char * test;
    int test2;

public:
    Config();
};

Config::Config(void)
{
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    boost::property_tree::xml_parser::read_xml("config.xml", pt);

    try
    {
        test = pt.get<char*>("base.char");
        test2 = pt.get<int>("base.int");
    }
    catch(std::exception e)
    {
        //something wasn't specified
    }
}
```

And the XML file:

```
<base>
    <char>test</char>
    <int>10</int>
</base>
```

First I thought it's because I didn't allocate space for the string but neither malloc() nor new char[] helped.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you tried `pt.get<std::string>("base.char");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/tutorial.html) tutorial I think you need to use `std::string` instead of `char*` to get string values.
So the line `test = pt.get<char*>("base.char");` would then be `test = pt.get<std::string>("base.char");`. (Assuming you change `test`'s type to `std::string` as well).